# This year's sets

Tags: real-analysis

This is an exercise from set theory, and I really can't solve it so I need help.
For set A $\subset$ **R** we say that is *this year's* set if for every finite subset B $\subset$ A stands $\sum_{b \in B} b \in [0,2020]$. Prove that every *this year's* set is subset of some maximal *this year's* set.

My idea to solution was Zorn's lemma. I can prove that there exists at least one maximal element in set of all *this year's* sets, but that does not mean every *this year's* set is a subset of some maximal *this year's* set.

Comment: You can just apply Zorn's Lemma to the family of *this year's* sets containing a given *this year's* set. This yields that any given *this year's* set is contained in a maximal (do you see why?) *this year's* set.

Comment: You want to look at the collection of this year's sets containing the picked one, not all of them

Comment: Okey, that was really easy, I see my mistake. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was observed in the comments that a solution is immediate with ZL. Another approach is as follows.

It is immediate from the definition that every element of a TYS (=this year's set) $A$ is non-negative. If $A$ has a finite number of elements then their sum must be $k\le 2020$. In that case the required maximal set is found by adjoining (if necessary) 0 and $2020-k$ to $A$.

$A$ cannot be uncountable, because then it would contain an uncountable number of elements greater than $1/n$ for some positive integer $n$ and would get a contradiction by picking $2021n$ of them.

The remaining case is $A$ countably infinite. Call the elements $a_1,a_2,\dots$. Then the partial sums $a_1+\dots+a_n$ are all bounded above by 2020 and increasing, so they must converge to a point $k$ in $[0,2020]$. Take $B$ to be the set $A\cup\{0,2020-k\}$. It is evidently a maximal TYS containing $A$.

Comment: Very nice, and very subtle use of the axiom of choice. (Which I suspect can be omitted, but that's irrelevant.)

Answer (score 0):

If every *this year*'s set is a subset of some maximum *this year*'s set $M$, then $\lbrace x\rbrace \subset M$ for every $x\in [0,2020]$, which means that $[0,2020]\subset M$ and then $M$ is not *this year*'s set...

Comment: But that is evidently not what the OP meant. The assumption is that every this year's set is contained in a **maximal** this year's set.

Comment: It doesn't be only one maximal element. You can have infinite maximal elements and every this year's set is subset of some of them.

Comment: @Toni: Maximum is not the same as maximal.

Comment: Oh, I see now. I will correct that.